# Visual Studio extension for clearing clipboard ring

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I use the clipboard ring a lot usually with 2-4 times i cycle thru. And all the other items i don't use but i have to cycle thru them. I looked around for a extension that could clear the existing cache of items in the ring. I could not find one.
Currently to get around it I recopy over and over till the list is full with the ones i need, or restart studio if it's going to be a long repeated task.

I was curious if anyone know any extension that could do this. Or any way I can tap into it, writing my own extension, I got the sdk but do not know how to connect in to clipboard ring.

I am using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have it as a macro. I just go to a newline within any open file in Visual Studio and press Ctrl+C a multitude of times to clear out the clipboard ring.

Comment: I was thinking more of a extension, not macro's. I actually taught they took macros out. Isn't there extensions that tap into studio itself, maybe there is a way to tap the clipboard ring itself.